# Realizar test a clases y genera el resultado de dicha clase para realizar el test de la clase siguiente

Tags: python

El script que arranca mi application tiene esta estructura

```
class cnv_classifier:

    def__init__(self,user_input):
    
    # First class
    data = ReadFile(user_input)
    data_loaded = data.load()

    # Second class
    cnv_df = Filter(data_loaded)
    cnv_df = cnv_df.filter_vcf_return_cnv()
```

Ahora con test.py, quiero realizar tests sobre`data_loaded` y `cnv_df`.

Para realizar tests sobre la primera clase he hecho esto

```
@pytest.fixture()
def file_to_test():
    file_to_test = 'path/file_name'
    return file_to_test

def test_data_loaded(file_to_test):
    data = ReadFile(file_to_test)
    data_loaded = data.load()
    assert ...
```

Si estoy haciendo esto de la forma correcta (que puede que no), quiero hacer un test similar al que acabo de hacer pero necesito `data_loaded` como input del nuevo test. Como puedo hacer esto?

Habia pensado poner un return al final de `test_data_loaded` para que me devuelva `data_loaded`   y utilizarlo en el siguiente test, asiu

```
def test_data_loaded(file_to_test):
    data = ReadFile(file_to_test)
    data_loaded = data.load()
    assert ...
    return data_loaded 

def test_filter(data_loaded):
    cnv_df = Filter(data_loaded)
    cnv_df = cnv_df.filter_vcf_return_cnv()
    assert ...
```

Pero esto no funciona. Como puedo entonces ir corriendo clase por clase my programa e ir realizando tests por cada clase utilizando la informacion de la clase anterior?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar variables globales, por ejemplo:

```
data_loaded = None

def test_data_loaded(file_to_test):
    global data_loaded
    data = ReadFile(file_to_test)
    data_loaded = data.load()
    assert ...


def test_filter(data_loaded):
    cnv_df = Filter(data_loaded)
    cnv_df = cnv_df.filter_vcf_return_cnv()
    assert ...
```

Otra forma podría ser utilizando `if` y utilizar `raise AssertionError ("Algo que desees mostrar")` para levantar la excepción de forma manual.

```
def test_data_loaded(file_to_test):
    global data_loaded
    data = ReadFile(file_to_test)
    data_loaded = data.load()
    if data_loaded:
        return data_loaded
    else:
        raise AssertionError ("Algo que desees mostrar")


def test_filter(data_loaded):
    cnv_df = Filter(data_loaded)
    cnv_df = cnv_df.filter_vcf_return_cnv()
    assert ...
```

En este caso deberías utilizar una variable para obtener lo que regresa la función `test_data_loaded`